# Any workflow similar to Source Control but only local?

Tags: git, version-control, versioning, source-control-explorer

Is there any software or method to work with source and version control, but only locally? I don't need, for now, to manage commits, team members or any online iterations, I just want to have an organized index.

I don't need any deep knowledge, I just need something to do a kickstart while I'm developing some websites. For now I'm just saving files with different names, but of course that doesn't work for long... I'd be really glad if I could have anything pretty simple like a local Git to use master and branches.

Comment: You can use Git locally.

Comment: Maybe read http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~blynn/gitmagic/ or a similar tutorial.

Comment: If it is only local, you still need to manage backing up your local repository. Just sign up for GitHub, BitBucket, or some other online Git host that allows free and private repositories. Even for just you, this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks to all! I'll check the links, but yeah, I believe I needed only a tutorial, but wasn't able to find a quick one.